# Retrieve localstorage value when value is change in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 framework and I have tried using local storage to store a network status

```
this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
this.local.set("status", this.status);
```

There are 2 values that, "Strong" and "Weak" that can be assigned to status dynamically.

---

I am able to get my the initial value of my local storage "status" value on initialization of every page.

```
toCheckStatus();
function toCheckStatus()
{
    self.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
    self.local.get('status').then((value) => 
    {
        console.log("status", value);
    });
}
```

this will return me a "Strong" or "Weak", which is what I want, but is there any methods or event to dynamically (On "status" value change) call "toCheckStatus()" function?

Workflow Example (pseudo-code):

1. On application start -> Check internet status (Background will keep checking and update local-storage value)
2. Store status to local-storage
3. Call a function to get the value **(How to dynamically call this function when my value change, is there any method?)**
4. If Status is Weak -> Show Weak Icon
5. If Status is Strong -> Show Strong icon

Comment: Aren't you setting the value as well? Just change the status icon when you set the status.

Comment: @Lifz hi Lifz, yes, I am changing the value as well, however the value is being altered in the background using a plugin while my icon is on my main page.

Comment: If the value changes inside your application, and you have control of when that value changes, you could fire a custom event. And then you could listen for that event in your application

Comment: @john Hi john, may I know if there's any simple sample of what you mentioned? I am quite bad at using eventlistener..

Comment: I have not done it myself in Angular 2, but there is an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338276/angular-2-event-broadcast that might help. Broadcast your value change, and then listen for that change.

Answer (score 3):

> How to dynamically call this function when my value change, is there any method?

A better solution will be using `observables`. You can use `observables` in your methods to emit events when a property is changed and then execute the code you need to execute.

This is a very simple example of using `observables`:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

    private storageObserver: any;
    public storage: any;

    constructor(...) {
        this.storageObserver= null;

        this.storage= Observable.create(observer => {
            this.storageObserver= observer;
        });
    }

    public yourMethod(): void { 

        // This method changes the value of the storage
        // ...

        // Notify to the subscriptor that the value has changed
        this.storageObserver.next(newValue);
    }
```

And then in your page:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/my-new-page/my-new-page.html',
  providers: [..., StorageService ]
})
export class MyNewPage {

    constructor(..., private storageService : StorageService ) {

        // Initialize all the things you need
        // ... 

        this.storageService.storage.subscribe((newValue) => {
                // This code will execute when the property has changed and also
                // you'll have access to the object with the information that
                // your service sent in the next() call.
                this.doWhatYouWant(newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

===========================================

**EDIT:**

If you need to update something in the view, beacuse of something that has changed in the background, you will have to let Angular know of that change. One way to do it is by using `Zones`. You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174997/angular-2-ionic-2-detect-if-an-object-was-modified#answer-38180523) to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a `BehaviorSubject` along with the *Storage* module from Ionic.

Create a BehaviorSubject that you call `.next()` whenever you set a key in *Storage* and subscribe to that BehaviorSubject to get the updated value.

A code example of this:

```
let storageObserver = new BehaviorSubject(null)

this.storage.set("key", "data")
storageObserver.next(null)

setTimeout(() => {
  this.storage.set("key", "new data")
  storageObserver.next(null)
}, 5000)

storageObserver.subscribe(() => {
  this.storage.get("key")
    .then((val) => console.log("fetched", val))
})
```

This will set a key in local storage which will be logged to the console, and asynchronously update that key after 5 seconds which then will be logged again to the console. You could refactor the setting of the key and updating the BehaviorSubject to a function.

Answer (score -1):

Would it suffice to poll it? It might not be the cleanest way but it would get the data you need.

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Check localStorage every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I am already using interval to achieve this, however I would like to know if there is any other ways of doing this because I wouldn't want my background to keep looping..

Comment: There is a `storage` event but per the specs, it's supposed to only fire on any pages that aren't 'this' page when the storage changes. I think the idea they had was, "well you're changing it, do something when you change it" :)