# Angular 7. How control variable on page(dashboard.page.ts) from another page (landing-in.page.ts)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Helo i'm new on angular 7 and ionic 4. how do you control the variables on the dashboard page from another page?.

I have tried to make simple logic in my application. control tbFor with the setToolbar function at dashboard.page.ts from landing-in.page.ts but it doesn't work. and an error appears

```
(ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError (AppModule) [LandingInPage -> DashboardPage] :).
```

but this problem can be lost when I try to import dashboard.page.ts to app.module.ts and add it to providers. but when I run it and I give console.log the setToolbar results in "true", but the fact is that when the page loads the value of the instance the variable tbFor is still in the value "false".

this is an example of dashboard.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { MenuController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth/auth.service";
@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.page.scss"]
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
  tbFor = {
    divCS: false,
    divGA: false,
    divTC: false
  };

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public menu: MenuController,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.menu.enable(true, "sideMenu");
  }

  setToolbar(div) {
    if (div == "CS") {
      this.tbFor.divCS = true;
    } else if (div == "GA") {
      this.tbFor.divGA = true;
    } else if (div == "TC") {
      //Ignores
      this.tbFor.divTC = false;
    }
  }

  clearToolbar() {
    this.tbFor.divCS = false;
    this.tbFor.divGA = false;
    this.tbFor.divTC = false;
  }
}
```

this is a dashboard.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="ion-toolbar" color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Semua Dokumen
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <app-toolbar-cs *ngIf="tbFor.divCS"></app-toolbar-cs>
  <app-toolbar-ga *ngIf="tbFor.divGA"></app-toolbar-ga>

</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list lines="none" *ngFor="let doc of docs">
    <ion-item>
      <img src="../../assets/img/box-skeleton.png" class="doc-icon" slot="start">
      <ion-label class="doc-label" text-wrap>{{doc.title}}<br><small class="doc-date">{{doc.date}}</small></ion-label>
      <ion-badge slot="end">{{doc.badge}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="ion-tabcam">
    <div class="ion-tabcam-icon">
      <span class="mdi mdi-camera"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

this is a landing-in.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth/auth.service";
import { AppComponent } from "../app.component";
import { DashboardPage } from "../dashboard/dashboard.page";
@Component({
  selector: "app-landing-in",
  templateUrl: "./landing-in.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./landing-in.page.scss"]
})
export class LandingInPage implements OnInit {
  landingLoggedButton: boolean = false;
  landingSpinner: boolean = true;
  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private dashboard: DashboardPage
  ) {}

  setLandingLoggedButton(value: boolean) {
    this.landingLoggedButton = value;
  }

  setLandingSpinner(value: boolean) {
    this.landingSpinner = value;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionCheck();
  }

  delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async sessionCheck() {
    await this.authService.checkLoggedIn();
    await this.delay(2000);
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn == true) {
      this.appComponent.setSidebar(this.authService.getDivision);
      this.appComponent.setAvatar(this.authService.getAvatar);
      this.appComponent.setFullname(this.authService.getFullname);
      this.appComponent.setEmail(this.authService.getEmail);
      this.dashboard.setToolbar(this.authService.getDivision);  <-- look this
      this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
    } else {
      this.landingSpinner = false;
      this.landingLoggedButton = true;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is a my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MenuCsComponent } from "./components/menu/menu-cs/menu-cs.component";
import { MenuGaComponent } from "./components/menu/menu-ga/menu-ga.component";
import { MenuTcComponent } from "./components/menu/menu-tc/menu-tc.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { IonicStorageModule } from "@ionic/storage";
import { DashboardPage } from "./dashboard/dashboard.page";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuCsComponent,
    MenuGaComponent,
    MenuTcComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: "__ionicstorage",
      driverOrder: ["indexeddb", "sqlite", "websql"]
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    DashboardPage,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use services to keep shared variables. Create a new service and add it as a provider in you module

Comment: yes it works to start and the toolbar appears as expected. but when I log out and try to switch to another type of account. dashboard.page.ts does not update changes to the toolbar.

User toolbar (CS) = 5 icons, user toolbar (GA) = 4 icons.

Therefore I tried updating the dashboard.page.ts variable from landing-in.page.ts to update the toolbar for each change in the type of account that occurred, but it didn't work

Comment: Did you try to define a new service or did you add your component as a provider? Defining a service is the common practice to achieve your expected behavior.

Comment: If you using a shared service, define observables and subscribe them from the pages which need to detect the changes in the variable.

Comment: I have created a variable on toolbar.service.ts and something can be observed. I also made a "subscription" on dashboard.page.ts and added services to the provider "dashboard.page.ts". this works well when I simulate changes using the <ion-button (click) = "getChangeService ('test data')"> Click Me </ ion-button>. but I tried changing the variable value from the page before the dashboard was loaded. it doesn't give real results

Comment: I tried to follow the advice in this forum. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176181/retrieve-localstorage-value-when-value-is-change-in-ionic-2

Comment: Can you recreate this on stackblitz, so i could be able to help you.