# Communication between deep nested components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to communicate between B3 and A2, is there any option without sending an event through all parents (B3 -> B1 -> main-app -> A1 -> A2 ) ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Do I get it right, for my case i need to use service? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please broadcast your event. Broadcasting is for passing events from on end of a tree to another, if the cost of travelling, with input/output becomes too much to bear.

Example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338276/angular-2-event-broadcast