# Send Variabel to another component in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I want to send a variable to another component.

HTML-doc in component A where I want to send user.id to component B

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" *ngFor="let user of users">
 <a routerLink="/profile"  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="testFunc(user.id)">
  {{user.name}}
 </a>
</li>
```

Component A where I want to send the id to component B (This is where I'm stuck)

```
 testFunc (id: JSON): string {
    //Send to component B
  }
```

I don't know if this is enough information but I can provide with more if needed.

Comment: You can use a broadcaster event as describe in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338276/angular-2-event-broadcast

Comment: How are Component A & B related (parent-child, siblings, or unrelated at all)? Where are they present in your app?

Comment: Should be parent-child but I think its unrelated atm

Comment: It does depend on how the components are related, could you please show your template showing both components or at least an overview of how it looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code when you click on the link you go to /profile page.
So if the content B is the profile component you can send your user.id throw the router parameter like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile', user.id]">
```

Of course configure the right route before. You can check these documentations:

- https://angular.io/guide/router#optional-route-parameters
- https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

In app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
  {path: 'addProfile', component: AddProfileComponent }, 
  {path: 'listProfiles', component: ListProfilesComponent}, 
  {path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent}
]
```

And

In ProfileComponent

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
     private selectedId: number;

     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.route.paramMap
                 .switchMap(params => this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
       // second option
       this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.selectedId = +params['id'])
    }
}
```

OR

If when you click on the link you just want to send a value to a component which is in your page, you can use @Input decorator. Like this :

```
<componentA>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
        *ngFor="let user of users">

        <a routerLink="/profile"  routerLinkActive="active"
           (click)="testFunc(user.id)">{{user.name}}</a>
    </li>

    <componentB [inputName]="userId"></componentB>
</componentA>
```

In the ts files:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'componentA',
  templateUrl: 'url'
})
export class ComponentA {
  public userId: string = ""
  constructor() {}

  public function testFunc(id: string): void {
     this.userId = id
  }
}
```

....

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'componentB',
  templateUrl: 'url'
})
export class ComponentB implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputName: string;
  constructor() {}

  function ngOnInit(): void {
     console.log(inputName)
  }
}
```

Be careful, don't try to show your input variable into constructor that doesn't work

Comment: The first answer is what I'm looking for, but how will the component fetch the id? Through the constructor?

Comment: Because this is how my routes look like in `app.module.ts`

`const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'addProfile', component: AddProfileComponent },
{ path: 'listProfiles', component: ListProfilesComponent},
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
];`